# My App is getting stopped in portrait mode while working fine in landscape mode in IPAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, xcode6, three20

I am using **Xcode 6+** and **iOS simulator 8.3**

This issue is only came on iOS 8.3 its working proper in iOS 7 .

Issue -  Please find below my error in debug mode in console.

error **--->**

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   <TTNavigationController: 0x7facad82b680>.

Comment: You used the tag three20. Are you using three20? It has been updated for quite a while, and has never been developed for > iOS6.

Comment: three20 is a framework used in my app acutely i am modifying this app.